# Why unordered_set<string::iterator> does not work?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector

I'm trying to get a list of iterators to erase from a string. I wanted to do it with unsorted_set because access time is constant and I'll be doing lookup often but it gives me a compile error.
`unordered_set<string::iterator> to_erase`
However if i try to define `vector<string::iterator> to_erase` it works.

But then when I try to do:

`find(to_erase.begin(),to_erase.end(),it)`

It doesn't work

Comment: You might have an X-Y problem here--trying to find a solution for a problem with a solution to another problem--If you describe the over-problem someone may be able to suggest a better solution to the over-problem.

Comment: You want a list of iterators for erasing, yet you want to do lots of lookups in that list? If you're erasing something, surely you don't need to look it up more than once. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Remember that iterators are often quickly invalidated once you start deleting. I haven't found a direct reference to the invalidation rules for a `std::string` yet, but I doubt they'll be much different from a `std::vector`. Anyway, as you start deleting your way through your unordered list of iterators that can be deleted, odds are good you invalidate at least some of the later iterators before you get the chance to delete them

Answer (score 3):

I have not checked but it looks like the string iterator does not define a hash code. Anything stored in an unordered_* has to have a hash.

I am not sure how you would do it since the internal char* of the iterator is hidden from you.

---

Mooing Duck contributed the following from http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8d75d3ac153a799

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

struct str_it_hasher {
    std::size_t operator()(std::string::const_iterator it) const {
        return std::hash<const char*>{}(&*it);
    }
};


int main() {
    std::unordered_set<std::string::iterator, str_it_hasher> set;
    std::string a = "apple";
    set.insert(a.begin());
    set.find(a.begin());
    set.erase(a.begin());
}
```

Comment: You are correct. Quickly running it through g++ nets a cryptic error, but you get this important bit: 
```no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >)```

Comment: I believe you can pass a custom hashing functoid to `unordered_set`, which would solve the problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck Sure but what would you use that you can read from an iterator?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8d75d3ac153a799 The address of the character that it points at (You should edit this or something similar into your answer)

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh, sneaky!

Answer (score 2):

An iterator of a string can be easily converted back and forth to index:

```
auto idx = iter - str.begin();
auto iter = idx + str.begin();
```

Then you can store the indices.